# asyncF.cpp:24:31: error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std';

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, std

I am compiling my code with clang++ and this gives me an error saying
asyncF.cpp:24:31: error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std'

Here's my code

```
// c++ program that demonstrates async
// library for std::cout
#include <iostream>
//library for std::async and std::future
#include <future>
// check whether it is prime number or not
//parameter is the number that has to be checked
bool fnprime (int num)
{
std::cout << "Process started. . . Just wait. . . \n";
//loop starts here
for ( int i = 2 ; i<num ; ++i )
//if the mod is 0, return false, else return zero
if (num%i==0)
{
return false ;
}
return true ;
}
//main method
int main ()
{
// call the function fnprime() asynchronously to check whether the number is prime or not:
std::future<bool> fobj = std::async (fnprime,4);
//print the line to show the status
std::cout << "check whether the number 4 is prime or not . . \n";
//waits for the the function fnprime to return
bool bobj = fobj.get();
//prints the result
if (bobj) std::cout << "The number given is prime . . .  ! \n";
else std::cout << "The number given is not prime . . .  ! \n\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of Clang are you using? What flags and options do you pass to Clang? And please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* build output into your question.

Comment: Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)

Comment: clang++  asyncF.cpp -o asyncF

Comment: clang++ asyncF.cpp -o async
asyncF.cpp:11:36: error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std'
    std::future<int> asyncF = std::async(&square,12);
                              ~~~~~^
1 error generated.

Comment: Try `clang++ -std=c++11 -o asyncF asyncF.cpp`

Comment: clang++ =std=c++11 asyncF.cpp -o asyncF is wrong

Comment: clang++ -std=c++11 asyncF.cpp -o asyncF is right

Comment: To add crucial and important details to your questions, please ***[edit]*** them. Don't post it as comments.

Comment: it was your fault who typed = instead of -